# Find the jordan form of a given matrix

Tags: matrices

let $n,k\in\ N$ and $\lambda \in F$.
Find the rank and the Jordan form of matrix $$A={ J }_{ n }{ (\lambda ) }^{ k }$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$J_n(\lambda)^k$ is an upper-triangular matrix, and its diagonal elements will all be $\lambda^k$.  Thus, its rank is $n$, and its Jordan form is $J_n(\lambda^k)$

Comment: Your answer is wrong if $\lambda=0$.